# Ruby: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Enumerator:0x007f8683922870>

Tags: ruby, recursion, nomethoderror

**EDIT TWO**

I noticed that while running the program, it was also returning `nil` as the last item in the array. To fix this I changed my condition.

```
if array_list.empty? ----> if array_list.length == 1
```

This returns the array without `nil`

**EDIT**
Thanks to @mudasobwa for his help.

He pointed out a couple things wrong with my program: one with how I wrote array.index using [ ] instead of the required ( )

Also learned that I shouldn't put spaces between the method name and its parameters.

Updated code here, look at original to see how it had changed.

```
list_one = ["apple", "anna", "banana", "peach", "cherry", "kiwi", "pineapple"]

def sort_array(array_list, sorted_array=[])

  sorted_array.push(array_list.min)
  if array_list.empty? || array_list.nil?
    return sorted_array
  else
    array_list.delete_at(array_list.index(array_list.min))
  return sort_array(array_list, sorted_array)
end

end

sort_array(list_one)
```

If anyone has other improvements or suggestions, please let me know. As it is, this recursive function seems to work flawlessly, although I still have a lot to learn on how to implement recursive functions in the future. It can be hard to get my brain wrapped around it.

**END EDIT, ORIGINAL BELOW**

I'm reading through Chris Pine's book Learn to Program, and one of the exercises is to make a recursive sorting method to sort through a list of items.

Here is my code:

```
list_one = ["apple", "anna", "banana", "peach", "cherry", "kiwi", "pineapple"]

def sort_array (array_list, sorted_array=[])
  sorted_array = sorted_array
  sorted_array.push(array_list.index[array_list.min])
  if array_list.empty?
    return sorted_array
  else
    array_list.delete_at(array_list.index[array_list.min])
    return sort_array(array_list, sorted_array)
end

end

sort_array (list_one)
```

Now, Chris's book calls for using a wrapper function, which I tried incorporating, but it doesn't make any difference in this case. Just coming up with this has been a bit of a mind-boggler, and I needed to read up more on recursive functions to get to this point.

When running this, I get the error listed in the title. I haven't had any luck yet figuring this out, so I'm hoping someone here can shed some light on what I might be doing wrong.

If I incorporate Chris's wrapper function:

```
def sortme (some_array)
  sort_array(some_array, [])
end
```

the error remains the same, which makes sense considering that the wrapper function is just calling the sort_array function. I really don't see the need for it in this case.

Any thoughts? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: use `Array.sort` method to sort an Array...In your case `list_one.sort`

Comment: @DarshanPatel using `Array.sort` from the scratch instead of implementing an algorithm youself gives a born to copy-pasters-from-stack-overflow instead of good developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
sorted_array.push(array_list.index[array_list.min])
```

Either use [`Array#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-index) or [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
sorted_array.push(array_list.index(array_list.min))
# or sorted_array.push(array_list[array_list.min])
```

---

There are two (or more) glitches with this code:

```
sorted_array = sorted_array
```

is a noop. What did you want to accomplish with that?

And, in general, **never ever** put a space between a method name and an opening parenthesis starting a list of it’s parameters. It might not work as expected in some cases.

Comment: Thanks mate. I overlooked how I wrote that array.index function, and changing that to its correct format fixed my program. 

I also updated my program with the improvements you mentioned (mostly with my styling). I'm still new to Ruby, and I also make mistakes with wanting to style the way I do with JavaScript